# Migrating From Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) to Sybase IQ 15.4.0.3027

Tags: sql-server-2008, sybase, database-migration, sap-iq

I am working on migrating from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) to Sybase IQ 15.4.0.3027.
As part of this, I need to convert all objects including SPs, Views, Functions, Tables in SQL Server to Sybase IQ compatible format.

Are there any automation tools available that can speed up the migration process by reducing the manual work?

Thank you in advance!

Thanks,
Swapnil

Comment: PowerDesigner may be able to do that.  http://www.sap.com/pc/tech/database/software/powerdesigner-data-architect/index.html

Comment: @MichaelGardner, thanks for you help. I found another tool  from SAP that helps to migrate from custom applications to SAP databases. http://scn.sap.com/community/database/blog/2014/07/08/set-your-databases-free--with-exodus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to rethink a couple of things during this migration process. Just a few thoughts based on my experiences:

- Rework your queries to have only a minimum on columns involved. `SELECT * FROM table` is much (as in really a lot of) slower than having e.g. `SELECT name, loan FROM table` on IQ due to the way IQ is storing the data on disc. Having this in mind, IQ can be really, really fast
- SP are very slow on IQ compaired to MS SQL. Check out whether you could migrate some of them into views or similar; Also IQ is using Sybase SQLAnywhere as engine for running procedures which is only supporting a subset of T-SQL of MS SQL.
- There are no materialized views. Things you might have done with MV needs to be done on ETL process on IQ or with normal views
- UPDATE/INSERTS are slow in IQ. Consider of bulk loading data instead.
- IQ 15 is locking a lot during DML-actions (table lock). With RLV introduces with IQ16 there is a way to improve this

PowerDesigner is maybe the tool you are looking for. Also you might want to check to use the latest version of IQ ... By this time this should be IQ16 SP08 P02

Comment: Many thanks!! Your inputs are really helpful. After some more research, I was able to find SAP database migration tool for migrating custom applications to SAP databases. http://scn.sap.com/community/database/blog/2014/07/08/set-your-databases-free--with-exodus